# Problems with Azure Authentication in Bot with botframework v4

Tags: c#, oauth, botframework

I have created a bot with the core bot template in visual studio and deployed it in Windows Azure. Since I want to use calendars in Exchange online, I have configured an App registration with respective Graph configuration.
I have configured settings for Azure Authentication in the bot settings in the Azure portal and updated the OAuthPrompt Settings in my code with the connection name used in the configuration.
This is how the different parts in the config look like:

**App authentication Settings:**

[image]

**Graph API Permissions**

[image]

**Authentication Settings in the Web App Bot configuration (I have removed App ID and App secret in the screenshot)**

[image]

In the code, I have created a ComponentDialog with waterfall steps below:

```
        public ScheduleMeetingDialog(IStatePropertyAccessor<ScheduleMeetingState> userProfileStateAccessor, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
        : base(nameof(ScheduleMeetingDialog))
    {

        ScheduleMeetingStateAccessor = userProfileStateAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userProfileStateAccessor));
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            InitializeStateStepAsync,
            PromptForParticipantsStepAsync,
            SaveParticipantsInStatusStep,
            PromptAutenticationStepAsync,
            FinalStepAsync
        };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(scheduleMeetingDialogId, waterfallSteps));
        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(validateParticipantsDialogId, ValidateParticipants));
        AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
            nameof(OAuthPrompt),
            new OAuthPromptSettings
            {
                ConnectionName = "SMALogin",
                Text = "You need to be logged in to go ahead. Please login",
                Title = "Login",
                Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
            }));
    }
```

The logon window appears in my bot as configured

[image]

after clicking the "Logon" button, the Microsoft Azure Logon window appears as expected. When I log in, I get an error message "Bad request" and the processing of the bot stops.

I have to cancel the action and send my intent anew. This time, the bot gets the authentication token without showing the logon dialog.

What am I doing wrong, making the "Bad request" message showing up and stopping the further processing in my bot?

In Fiddler I see the following:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to work with some breakpoints?

Comment: And what happens if you do the "TestConnection" with the "service provider connection setting"

Comment: @ Seppe Mariën: Yes, I have set breakpoints. As soon as the OAuthPrompt is part of the Dialogs, no breakpoint is hit anymore and Logon is shown, regardless if it is a part of the waterfall or not. I tested the connection after configuration and after I received the "Bad Request". The test was successful and showed a Token.

Comment: Can you paste the url of the bad request? Also, when you say "the processing of the bot stops", what do you exactly mean by that? You can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug the request and find the inner error message in the response.

Comment: @ranusharao: I mean, I have to reset the bot in the emulator, because no other utterances I make in the chat is being processed. I just gets stuck. I will try to find out more details with help of Fiddler and update the post.

Comment: I have done some more testing on the Azure AD Connection. The underlying Azure AD App I am using was created with the "new" interface (NOT a legacy App). The connection test apparently only works after the first test and giving consent. All following tests fail with a bad request.

Comment: Can you try testing the connection by changing the Tenant ID to the [Tenant ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth#get-the-tenant-id-for-your-active-directory) for your Azure Active Directory? In the meanwhile, I will try to reproduce the issue and update you once I find a work around.